# Converting files from Hyper -v to VMware

Tags: vmware, converters, hyper-virtualization

I need to solve a problem:

I have files from Hyper -V Virtual Machine
it is formats .vmcx, vmgs and vmrs, i need convert it to Vmware. I try do it with StarWind V2V Converter, but when i want choose file, converter do not detect any files in my folder with .vmcx, vmgs and vmrs files.

Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that VMCX, VMRS and VMGS are basically VM configuration, running and guest state files. These do not contain the actual data, meaning the VM disk (VHDX).

I've used Starwinds V2V multiple times and it should detect a VM automatically. Presuming you're running the tool on a Hyper-V host with that VM of course (if you have only VM configuration files in some other place, it won't work). You don't need to point it to configuration files. Here's a guide on this I've found: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/VMfromMicrosoftHyperVServertoVMwareESXiServer.html.

Alternatively, you can point it to and convert a VHDX file to VMDK. Keep in mind that if you convert a VHDX, you would need to create a new VM on ESXi and attach the converted VMDK to it.